# Submersion $S^3 \to T^2$ and from $T^2 \to S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S^n$ be the $n$-dimensional sphere, and let $T^n = (S^1)^n$ be the $n$-dimensional torus. Does there exist a submersion from $S^3$ to $T^2$? From $T^2$ to $S^2$?

I was thinking that to get a submersion from $T^2 \to S^2$ you could take each point $x \in T^2$ and map it to $x/||x||$ and hope that the jacobian of this map has full rank. But I have no idea how to get a submersion from $T^2 \to S^2$?

Comment: There's probably many ways of arguing here. One possibility is quoting Ehresmann's theorem, which implies that a submersion between compact connected smooth manifolds is automatically a fiber bundle. Then, you could use the LES of homotopy groups to relate the fundamental group of the base with the number of connected components of a fiber.